# Mysql C# - Calling a Stored Procedure with enum as output parameter

Tags: c#, mysql, stored-procedures, enums

I would like to call the following stored procedure In order to select the color of a suboject:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `get_color`(   
       IN code VARCHAR(32) ,
       OUT color enum('Blue','Green','White','Orange','Black'))
BEGIN
       SELECT `Objects`.`subobject_id`
       INTO @subobject
       FROM `Objects`
       WHERE `Objects`.`code` = code;

       SELECT `SubObjects`.`color`
       INTO color
       FROM `SubObjects`
       WHERE `SubObjects`.`id` = @subobject;

END
```

The procedure works fine when being run from My sql query windows in the following way:

```
set @object_code = 39164;
CALL get_color(@object_code, @color);
select @color;
```

I would like to achieve the same result in my c# application running the following code:

```
MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand();
command.Connection = connection;
command.CommandText = "get_color";
command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@code", code);
command.Parameters["@code"].Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input ;

command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@color", MySqlDbType.VarChar);
command.Parameters["@color"].Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;

MySqlDataReader rdr = command.ExecuteReader();

if ((rdr != null) && (rdr.HasRows) && (rdr.FieldCount == 1))
{
    rdr.Read();
    color = rdr.GetString(0);
    rdr.Close();
}
else
{
    rc = false;
}
```

Unfortunately... when I call 'command.ExecuteReader()', it throws the following exception:

An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format.

I banging my head on the keyboard in the attempt to understand what's wrong in the format :(

Any hints?

Comment: Do not try to read the reader. Close it and read the value of the Output parameter

Comment: @Steve I cant even reach the point of reading the reader, Exception is thrown as soon as I execute the command :(

Comment: I would try to remove the AddWithValue calls and use the more precise _Add(parameterName, ParameterType).Value =_  where you could set the exact datatype for the parameter

Comment: Try adding log to the connection and check it.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-programming-tracing.html

Comment: @Steve - Thanks! Using "the more precise Add" made it work, thanks as well for the suggestion of not reading the reader.

Comment: @FernandoC - Thanks for the suggestion about the logger on the connection, it will definately prove to be VERY helpful in the future.